# Set TD at runtime (depending on Label.text)

Tags: asp.net

I have some tabular data, when the label has some specific value I need to make it show off.
Trying to do by styling the TD.
My C# sets the value for `Label1.text`

Can you think of any other way for doing so? It's throwing ambiguity error.

```
 <% if (Label1.Text == "1") { %>
            <td style="background:#ffedad; border:#e3a345; color:#cd5c0a"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" /></td>
 <% }  else {%>
      <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" /></td>
 <% } %>
```

**EDIT**

Did something else (and cleaner).

Worked on some code behind variables along with some new `td.alt` on my css file to get the value of the label. If it's `1`, then I set a 
`classLabel` variable to `alt` and then I just set the `class` inside the `td`

```
<td class="<%classLabel%>"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" /></td>
```

Still, I'm getting and error on this last line in my aspx page, any ideas where the error is?

Comment: Something like <td class="<%=GetClassLabel(Label1.Text)%>"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" /></td> would be way better.  (BTW : don't forget the '=' in <%=)
About your error, I bet it comes from somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with a single line :

```
<td <%=Label1.Text != "1"?"":"style='background:#ffedad; border:#e3a345; color:#cd5c0a'"%>><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" /></td>
```

Setting the style code behind and with a css class would be cleaner IMHO

Hope this will help

Comment: thanks, got this error. Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Comment: great! followed your advice and did something cleaner, check edit please. If you can, let me know what's my error there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can call the code behind method which will return the formatted HTML string that can be directly rendered by the browser. In that code behind method you can do almost anything: access any type of database or any business logic.

Possible return div element encapsulating the content (without style).
You can return divs with different ids or classes by having if-else logic inside the code-behind method. Then you can write different CSS styles to apply to different divs.

```
<% if (Label1.Text == "1") { %> 
        <td style="background:#ffedad; border:#e3a345; color:#cd5c0a">
        <%# generateOutput() %></td> 
<% }  else {%> 
  <td> <%# generateOutput() %> </td> 
<% } %>
```

Instead of having if-else in asp.net markup, you can simply have

```
<%# generateOutput() %>
```

and return the whole content from code behind and write styles in CSS files.

If the content to be displayed is less or less complicated this second approach will work, otherwise you may prefer first approach.

However if you are accessing the data directly from database you can you ASP.NET data controls like GridView, style them in templates and also filter the data using querystring or form values.